# Expand and collapse a colapsingToolBar with a button in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, toolbar

I want to expand and collapse a CollapsingToolBar in android studio
when i click a button.

I want it collapsed by dafault. Im doing something wrong and i dont know what, thanks for the help.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //maybe this doesnt go here, im trying to make it collapse by default
    var start = appbar.setExpanded(false)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        if(start == appbar.setExpanded(false)){
            start = appbar.setExpanded(true)

        }else{
            start = appbar.setExpanded(false)
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var isAppbarExpanded = false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        if(!isAppbarExpanded){
            appbar.setExpanded(true)
            isAppbarExpanded = true
        }else{
            appbar.setExpanded(false)
            isAppbarExpanded = false
        }

    }

}
```